# I want the color-theme to highlight the text in the buffers but not change the colors in the menu bar

Tags: themes, menu-bar

I loaded a color-theme (`manoj-dark`) to highlight text in the buffers but it also changed the color of the menu bar. Now the menu bar icons are setting in a black background and the title bar of the window is also black. The slider bar did not change color nor did the mode line:[image]  I want to colorize the text in the buffers without changing the colors of the menu bar.  How can I do that?

GNU Emacs 26.1
macOS 10.13.6

Comment: Is the recipe to reproduce this from `emacs -Q` just to load that theme? Please also provide a reference (e.g. URL or ELPA repository info) for that theme.